Issue with addEventListener on fileupload change 'showing pdf file'
I'm using pdf.min to show a pdf doc on my page so i found this javascritp code
<script>
                                                    const PDF_TYPE = "application/pdf";
                                                    const TXT_TYPE = "text/plain";

                                                    document.getElementById('FileUpload1').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


                                                    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                                                        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
                                                        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                                                            let fileType = files[i].type;
                                                            if (fileType === PDF_TYPE) {
                                                                handlePDFFile(files[i]);
                                                            } else if (fileType === TXT_TYPE) {
                                                                handleTxtFile(files[i])
                                                            } else {
                                                                console.error(`cannot handle file type: ${fileType}`)
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    function handleTxtFile(file) {
                                                        var reader = new FileReader();
                                                        reader.onload = (function (reader) {
                                                            return function () {
                                                                var contents = reader.result;
                                                                var lines = contents.split('\n');

                                                                document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = contents;
                                                            }
                                                        })(reader);

                                                        reader.readAsText(file);
                                                    }

                                                    function handlePDFFile(file) {
                                                        var reader = new FileReader();

                                                        reader.onload = (function (reader) {
                                                            return function () {
                                                                var contents = reader.result;
                                                                var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(contents);

                                                                loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
                                                                    pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
                                                                        var scale = 1.5;
                                                                        var viewport = page.getViewport({
                                                                            scale: scale,
                                                                        });

                                                                        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                                                                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                                                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                                                                        canvas.width = viewport.width;

                                                                        var renderContext = {
                                                                            canvasContext: context,
                                                                            viewport: viewport
                                                                        };
                                                                        page.render(renderContext);
                                                                    });
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        })(reader);
                                                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                                    }
                                                </script>

so i used it and it working in first page but when i want to use it again in an other page it doesn't work , i use the same code with the same script links  but it doesn't show any thing
i try the same code in two diffirents pages where it work for one page and not for the other
